# Build failing because of app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android

Sorry if i put this twice, but I tried browsing through a lot of threads here, but I was not able to locate it. 
In some threads it was mentioned to execute the gradle clean command and it works. I tried that too however for me it did not work.

Below is my dependency code

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6")
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.0.17")
compile("org.webjars:jquery:2.0.3-1")
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile project(path: ':shoppingCartLibrary')
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

And when I try to build my project I am getting this error:-

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this problem. I had to remove some of the dependencies which was not actually required. my current dependencies look like

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

This in turn was giving me an error which I solved by excluding

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```